# C# - Reading from a file on a referenced DLL

Tags: c#

I have a `DLL` with some files I want to read from.
The problem is that even though I set the files on `Copy Always`, when compiling my console app the files doesn't get copied to the output.

Is there any option to do so?

Comment: If those files are part of the class library project, with that setting, they will be copied to the output folder of the class library. But the console application, referencing that class library project, won't get those files. You sure you're not better off embedding the files as resources in that class library?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen This dll is a private nuget project. This files contain SQL code which I want to access. I wanted to store them in SQL files in the nuget dll, Now I am thinking maybe I should store them in another way.

Comment: @omriman12 You can use after build events to trigger xcopy in the project settings.

Comment: Did you set the Build Action to *Content*?